# Awk programming in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, awk

How to print a whole record and ask for input (getline) together in the same awk file?

This is the code of the awk file. It does not print the list of symptoms from the input file, only asks the question when I run it.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
print $0
printf"Enter the symptoms you are experiencing according to the numbering given in the list\n  
getline symptom<"-"
}
$1==symptom{
print $2
}
```

This was my input file:

```
1 Chestpainortightne 6 Triggeredbyallergens
2 HeadacheandFacialpain 7 Drycough
 3 Chillswithsweating 8 Triggeredbysmoking
4 Painondeepbreathing 9 Fever
5 Coughwithsputum 10 Wheeze
```

Comment: AFAICR, there is no `$0` inside the BEGIN block; it is executed before the first line is read.  You're missing a close quote at the end of the `printf` line, too.  It would help to see the command line invocation, and the input you expected to provide.  Are you sure you need `getline`; the `FNR == NR` technique would allow you to process the input file and then process the other data — which could come from standard input aka typing if you specify the file name `-` to `awk`.  Is the input really as shown or is that the input converted to 2 sets of 2 columns?

Comment: Getline is not important.I tried to run it your way but that only prints the list of symptoms.It does not ask the user the question.What should I do? and please explain in a little simpler terms as its been only 4 months since i am using ubuntu and a month since we learnt very basic AWK programming.So i am not able to comprehend much? n we havent done arrays in awk programming

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. If you have any other "awk book", throw it away as it is out of date at best.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data file is called `data` and looks like:

```
1 Chestpainortightne
2 HeadacheandFacialpain
3 Chillswithsweating
4 Painondeepbreathing
5 Coughwithsputum
6 Triggeredbyallergens
7 Drycough
8 Triggeredbysmoking
9 Fever
10 Wheeze
```

then you should be able to use this, which specifies `-` as one of the two input files so the script reads from standard input after processing the `data` file.

```
awk 'FNR == NR { symptom[$1] = $2; print $0; next }
    #FNR == 1  { print "Enter your symptoms by number, one per line" }
               { print $0 " ==> " symptom[$1] }' data -
```

If uncommented, the prompt appears after, not before, the first line of input from the user, which is a nuisance.  With GNU Awk, you could use:

```
gawk 'FNR == NR { symptom[$1] = $2; print $0; next }
      BEGINFILE { print "Enter your symptoms by number, one per line" }
                { print $0 " ==> " symptom[$1] }' data -
```

The `BEGINFILE` pattern is only invoked at the start of the second file, `-`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
1 Chestpainortightne    6 Triggeredbyallergens
2 HeadacheandFacialpain 7 Drycough
3 Chillswithsweating    8 Triggeredbysmoking
4 Painondeepbreathing   9 Fever
5 Coughwithsputum       10 Wheeze

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    db = ARGV[1]
    delete ARGV[1]
    ARGC--
    while ( (getline line < db) > 0 ) {
        print line
        split(line,flds)
        for (i=1;i in flds;i+=2) {
            n2v[flds[i]] = flds[i+1]
        }
    }
    close(db)
    printf "Pick a number: "
}
{
    printf "You selected %d (%s)\n", $0, n2v[$0]
    exit
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 Chestpainortightne    6 Triggeredbyallergens
2 HeadacheandFacialpain 7 Drycough
3 Chillswithsweating    8 Triggeredbysmoking
4 Painondeepbreathing   9 Fever
5 Coughwithsputum       10 Wheeze
Pick a number: 2
You selected 2 (HeadacheandFacialpain)
```

Reading data from a database in the BEGIN section before you start processing is one of those rare situations where use of getline can be appropriate but make sure you read and fully understand all of the caveats at http://awk.info/?tip/getline before using getline.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{ 
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1)
        next 
    }
    { print }
    END{
        print ""
        while(1){
            printf "Enter the symptoms you are...: " 
            getline symptom<"-"
            if(symptom in a){
                printf "You selected %d (%s)\n", symptom, a[symptom]
                break
            }
        }
    }
' file <(sed 's/$/\n/' file|column -t)

1  Chestpainortightne     6   Triggeredbyallergens
2  HeadacheandFacialpain  7   Drycough
3  Chillswithsweating     8   Triggeredbysmoking
4  Painondeepbreathing    9   Fever
5  Coughwithsputum        10  Wheeze

Enter the symptoms you are...: 1234
Enter the symptoms you are...: foo
Enter the symptoms you are...: 5
You selected 5 (Coughwithsputum)
```